# Iterate Over Object Properties to Check if Any Exist in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

I'm building a calculator app using JavaScript. When a user clicks on an operator (+, -, *, /), I want to first check if any other operators have already been entered. I'm storing all button presses in an array. If an operator already exists, the first operation performed will be to either replace the operator with the one pressed (if no second number exists to perform an operation on) or to perform an equals operation and then add the new operator to the end of the results. For example, if the user enters "1 + 1" and then enters another "+" operator, I want it to perform the 1+1 operation and then store the next operation as "2 + [whatever gets entered next]".

I have an object that stores functions associated with each operator. Is it possible to do something like:

```
var ops = {
  "+": function(a,b) {return a + b},
  "-": function(a,b) {return a - b},
  // etc...
};

// And then in the code
if (log.indexOf(ops) >= 0) { // perform math, then add new op}
```

That last line is checking if the log already contains one of the operators. Is something like this shorthand approach possible, or do I need to iterate over the object properties?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gregrholden/sbobaszj/1/) of what I'm looking at, attempting the object.keys(ops) approach recommended by the first commenter.

Comment: object.keys(ops)

Comment: Are you looking for: `if (ops in log) { ` ? You'll need to show more of your code to see where you got stuck.

Comment: ops.hasOwnProperty(operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways to do it would be:

```js
log.some( x => Object.keys(ops).includes(x) )
```

Please see [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: This works, but only if I iterate through each object property. I'm looking for a shorthand way. For instance, passing all keys of the object to the includes() array one time and having it check for all properties at once.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Object.keys(ops).includes(searchElement)` ?

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gregrholden/sbobaszj/5/) for what I mean. Thanks

Comment: `log.some( x => Object.keys(ops).includes(x) )`

Comment: That did it. Thanks, Arash! Create this as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gregrholden/sbobaszj/8/) here with solution.

Comment: Glad it helped.